# Material-UI inline styling SEO impact

Tags: css

I'm using [Material UI for React](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) and they're using inline style since the 0.8.0 version.

How much does this solution has an impact on the SEO ?

Most SEO checkers are reporting issues for inline styling on websites using them but Material UI is too good to be ditched for that only reason (unless it's a big deal).

There are some [alternatives](https://github.com/sarink/material-ui-with-sass) but they're not as up to date as the official Material UI...

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has no connection to SEO, except page load time, maybe.
Inline CSS is never a good practice for future product support. But I would not worry about SEO at all, as the main thing for SEO is your unique content and quality links to your page :)

Comment: Nick is right. Especially given that you can just use className="custom-css-class" to apply css classes instead of using inline.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I found a nice [article](https://www.ctheu.com/2015/08/17/react-inline-styles-vs-css-stupid-benchmark/) that tests the response time of a page with and without inline style using React. As you mentioned it doesn't have much of an impact on the SEO because the load time for 'normal pages' is still pretty good. Especially if you restrict inline style to material only.
Thanks again.